# erro no pow() e no sqrt()

Tags: c

Estou encontrando um erro nesse código, mas pra mim parece tudo certo.
Erro do terminal depois de tentar compilar(gcc):

> [na função "main": exercise-11.c:(.text+0x6e): referência não definida
> para "sqrt" /usr/bin/ld: exercise-11.c:(.text+0xd8): referência não
> definida para "pow" collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main() {

    double number, raiz, quadrado;

    printf("Digite um número:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &number);

    if (number>0)
    {
        printf("O numero é maior que 0 então vou tirar a raiz quadrada\n");
        raiz = sqrt(number);
        printf("O resultado da raiz quadrada de %.0lf é %.0lf", number, raiz);

    } else if (number<0) {
        
        printf("O numero é menor que 0 então vou elevar ao quadrado\n");
        quadrado = pow(number, 2);
        printf("O resultado do quadrado de %.0lf é %.0lf", number, quadrado);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Especifique o parâmetro -lm na compilação.

Comment: como assim? não consegui resolver

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o gcc: `gcc -o executavel fonte.c -lm`

Comment: obrigado, não conhecia esse parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Assim você irá conseguir utilizar a biblioteca math.h ou coloque nos parâmetros de compilação(-1m) da sua IDE
gcc -o </path/do/programa/programa.c> -1m